Mixed Effects with repeated measures design and covariate included
I have a dataset that consists of the oxygen consumption (MO2) values for 3 different species of fish. My experiment was a repeated measures design where I measured MO2 of the same 14 fish per species at 4 different temperature points (15C, 20C, 25C and 30C). I also recorded the weight of all fish used in the study. I am trying to run a mixed effects model in R with individual as a random variable (to accommodate the repeated measures design) and with weight included as a covariate (I already ran an ANCOVA and confirmed weight as a significant covariate with MO2, so I want to make sure I account for that in the mixed effects analysis). Statistically speaking, is this an appropriate set up? If yes, how would I do this R? Would I be able to do a Tukey post hoc test afterwards as well - I want to know how each of the species' MO2 values differ from each other within each temperature, in addition to how the MO2 values within each species differs from itself at different temperatures.

I think for your case, if we were using something like lme4 in R, your model would look something like this:
fit <- lmer(oxy.dv ~ fish.species + temp + wt (1|fish.id), data = data)

Where oxygen is your DV, fish species is a factor variable entered as a main effect, temperature and weight are entered as covariates, and the fish clusters of repeated measures are estimated as random intercepts (as "fish ID").
As for the pairwise comparisons, one can also achieve this in R with the emmeans package (details here), with code that is similar to this, which produces the estimated marginal means (EMMs), conducts pairwise comparisons of each fish species, and plots them accordingly:
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)

#### Model ####
fit.1 <- lmer(oxy.dv ~ fish.species + temp + wt (1|fish.id), data = data)

#### Estimate EMM ####
emm <- emmeans(fit.1,"fish.species") # estimates marginal means

#### Plot and Contrast with Tukey ####
contrast(emm,"pairwise") # shows Tukey PWCs
plot(emm) # plots EMMs

Of course this is contingent upon estimating all of the fixed effects as main effects only. If you desired to make interactions between fish species and weight for example (I would imagine this would be relevant since fish species probably vary dramatically by weight), then you would instead estimate a model like this instead, where the * operator adds the main effects and interaction:
fit.2 <- lmer(oxy.dv ~ fish.species * wt + temp + (1|fish.id), data = data)

Furthermore, if you believe that the temperature -> oxygen consumption associations vary considerably between fish, then you can add random slopes:
fit.3 <- lmer(oxy.dv ~ fish.species * wt + temp + (1 + temp|fish.id), data = data)

Keep in mind though that this "maximal model" is difficult to fit if there is not enough random effect variance to support it (aka the model will crash, more on that here). So it may be good practice to plot the associations between temperature and oxygen by fish to see if this will even matter to add to the model.
